# How does a multi container Elasticbeanstalk environment update it's docker containers?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I've setup an EB instance that runs two Docker containers, these containers are retrieved from an ECS registry and have the correct push/pull setup.

So if I build a new docker image via codebuild and have it push to our registry, how does EB (using a multi docker container setup) pull in the new image? I've set my Dockerun file to point to the `latest` container! Here is my Dockerrun.aws.json file:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "rest-api",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/rest-api"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "thumbd",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/thumbd"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "rest-api",
      "image": "<ECS_REGISTRY_URL>",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "rest-api",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
          "readOnly": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "thumbd",
      "image": "<ECS_REGISTRY_URL>",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "thumbd",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
          "readOnly": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Question:

1. How does this work internally?
2. Is there something I need to setup to have EB automatically use the `:latest` container as soon as it updates?